# Javascript is not resizing iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I can't seem to get this iframe to resize

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setIframe(src, iwidth, iheight) {
            var cFrame = document.getElementById('contentFrame');
            cFrame.src = src;
            cFrame.width = iwidth;
            cFrame.height = iheight;
        }
    </script>
    <div>Getting Started
         <div onclick="setIframe('login.aspx','800px','1000px');">Set Up</div>
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="background-color:#CCC"><iframe src="support.htm" id="contentFrame" style="width:400px;height:500px"></iframe>
    </div>
```

For simplicity sake, I did not include a few wrapper divs because they are only used for style. However, the two outer divs above are in a div that is a flexbox, so they are being displayed horizontally rather than each taking up the whole horizontal space. I have the content div set to a width of 100%, and the first div set to a fixed width. As you can see, the iframe also starts off with a hard coded fixed width/height inline. Also note that restting the src for the iframe works in the js function, just not width and height.

Thx

Comment: That's what I believe my situation is. I colored the second div grey so that I can see how much space it has, and it has plenty accept the new size of the irame, but it does not resize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the style for the iframe instead (CSS):

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setIframe(src, iwidth, iheight) {
            var cFrame = document.getElementById('contentFrame');
            cFrame.src = src;
            cFrame.style.width = iwidth + 'px';
            cFrame.style.height = iheight + 'px';
        }
    </script>
    <div>Getting Started
         <div onclick="setIframe('login.aspx','800px','1000px');">Set Up</div>
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="background-color:#CCC"><iframe src="support.htm" id="contentFrame" style="width:400px;height:500px"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Comment: Whoops, of course that's the problem. Let me try it but I'm sure it will work.

Comment: I write a lot of jQuery but did this in js because it was simple enough, but forgot the style part of the dom object. thx. I'll mark this as accepted and the other as helpful

Answer (score 1):

You have inline styles that are overriding the width and height properties.

If you remove the inline styles, it should work

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function setIframe(src, iwidth, iheight) {
    var cFrame = document.getElementById('contentFrame');
    cFrame.src = src;
    cFrame.width = iwidth;
    cFrame.height = iheight;
  }
</script>
<div>Getting Started
  <div onclick="setIframe('login.aspx','800px','1000px');">Set Up</div>
</div>
<div id="content" style="background-color:#CCC">
  <iframe src="support.htm" id="contentFrame" width="400" height="500"></iframe>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could set `cFrame.style.width/height`

Answer (score 1):

Since you've got jQuery in your tags, I'll assume you're open to doing it the jQuery way.

```
$('#myframe').width('900');
$('#myframe').height('800');
```

If you don't want to use jQuery, @Dr.Flink's answer is the way to go.

Comment: You're answer is perfectly correct and helpful, just thought the other one answered in js terms which was how I decided to do this. You're right, I usually use jquery. Probably will next time.